# Formula for weighted averages

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a bit of a hybrid between a mathematical and an Excel issue. I currently have an Excel sheet with a list of yearly observations. To simplify, lets say that for five years I'm looking at:

> 2015=5
>    2014=3
>    2013=4
>    2012=1
>    2011=6

What I would like to do is write a formula that counts the number of values in question (`5` in this case), divides 100% of the weight and and makes each preceding value be worth 10% less than the last.

So in this case

> 2015 would be worth (roughly rounded) 24%
>    2014=22%
>    2013=20%
>    2012=18%
>    2011=16%

if you add the weight for each they add up to 100%.

As an example the numbers to be presented for weighting are:

> 1.225 for 2015 (5*.24)
>    .6615 for 2014 (3*.22)
>    .7938 for 2013 (4*.20)
>    .1786 for 2012 (1*.18)
>     .9645 for 2011 (6*.16)

I have calculated all of these numbers manually but would need a formula that can adapt to the number of periods being used as I will be adding more over time.

Comment: What happens if you have six periods - periods 3 and 4 are equal weight?

Comment: well the idea is that the formula takes the number of periods into account. so if you have six periods the weight (in descending order) would be: 21.5%, 19.4%, 17.4%, 15.7%, 14.1%, and 12.7%. The sum of which adds up to 100%. I'm pretty sure that this is a relatively simple algebraic formula that for some reason I can't put on paper at the moment.

Comment: I suggest you do some research on EWMAs - exponentially weighted moving averages. These are standard statistical formulae and charts to increase the weighting of more recent data, and to lessen the impact of more distant data. John Shewart was amongst the first to develop and use these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum of n terms (Sn) of an geometric series starting with `a` and having ratio `r` is:

```
Sn = a(1 − r^n)
    ___________
       1 − r
```

All you need to do is rearrange and solve for `a` given Sn=100, r=0.9 and n=number of terms....

```
a(1 − r^n) = Sn(1-r)

a = Sn(1-r)
    _______
    (1-r^n)
```

For 5 terms:

```
a = 100 * (1 - 0.9) / (1 - 0.9^5) = 24.419
```

for 10 terms:

```
a = 100 * (1 - 0.9) / (1 - 0.9^10) = 15.353
```